# Multiple Separate Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. This application contains a form for which I need to make multiple regular expression checks, which should have different errors depending on the issue.

Does anyone know the way in which I would go about having separate errors? I have tried using multiple RegularExpression annotations on one model property, but this throws an error upon compilation. Here is a sample of the code:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Distribution List Name")]
[StringLength(65, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 65 characters")]
[RegularExpression("^#(CONTOSO|MEGACORP|TESTCOMPANY)([-_A-Za-z0-9 ]+)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid company, or the name contains invalid characters (Allowed characters are alphanumeric, - and _)")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Ideally, I would like the check for the company at the start of the string, and the allowed character check to throw separate error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options you can consider

a. Create a custom attribute that allows it to be applied multiple times (using `AllowMultiple=true`).

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple=true)]
public class MyAttribute: RegularExpressionAttribute
{
  ....
}
```

and register it in `Global.asax.cs`

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(MyAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
```

Note, I haven't tested if this works with client side validation

b. Create a custom validator and test each regex separately and return the appropriate message.

```
public class MyAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
  ....
}
```

Comment: Do not use option a.See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652533/should-i-use-multiple-regularexpression-attributes/35658502#35658502

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do all your checks with the data attributes.
You can do it programmatically when you receive the form by doing something like :

```
if(!myCheckIsOkay)
    Modelstate.AddModelError("CompanyName", "the check of the company name was not correct")
//... Do other checks
if(Model.IsValid)
//Do something here with valid model
```