# How to validate a number with more than you restriction in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field is needed")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Can only be 9 characters long")]
[Display(Name = "Number")]
 public string Number { get; set; }
```

This is what I have. I'm making sure that the number can only have 9 characters, yet I also want it not to accept numbers that don't start with 1 or 2.

So if someone tries to create a 333333333 account, it wouldn't let him. How can I do such a thing?

Here is the View

```
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Number)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Number)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Number)
        </div>
```

Comment: Change your regular expression to exclude strings starting with numbers over 2. http://www.regexpal.com can help. The current regular expression looks like it prevents you from using any numbers in the string - is that what you wanted?

Comment: Can't open the link.
It let's me right anything with 9 characters long

Comment: This isn't what it does - the regular expression ^[0-9]+$ means match any character from 0 - 9 any number of times between the start and end of the string. You can put 1000 characters (as long as they are digits).

Comment: Try this link instead: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the regex you need to only allow 9 numbers and the first has to be 1 or 2

```
^[1-2][0-9]{0,8}$
```

So your property will be

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field is needed")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[1-2][0-9]{0,8}$", ErrorMessage = "Can only be 9 characters long")]
[Display(Name = "Number")]
 public string Number { get; set; }
```

NB: Your regex lets you have more than 9 numbers.

I use Debuggex to check my regex out, see yours explained here
https://www.debuggex.com/r/O0hseHDUms5Fhh0u

Comment: The `{1}` isn't necessary after the first character match - `^[1-2][0-9]{0,8}$` should work fine (sorry for being pedantic!)

Comment: Didn't know about debuggex.com - nice, even shows the match steps :)

Comment: It's basically taught me regex.... but now I've forgotten most I knew so its a life saver

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem yet I have another question :)

What if I want a different error message for the case where the first number is different from 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex should be something like this:

```
^[12]{1}\d{8}$
```

- [12]{1} = Any character in the list
- \d{8} = followed by 8
  digits

To display more than one error you could combine it with other validation rules such as Range or StringLength although I'm not sure of the order of precendence.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field is needed")]
[Range(100000000,299999999, ErrorMessage="Must be 9 characters and start with 1 or 2")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[1-2][0-9]{0,8}$", ErrorMessage = "Can only be 9 characters long and start with 1 or 2")]
[Display(Name = "Number")]
public string Number { get; set; }
```

Comment: What if I want a different error message for the case where the first number is different from 1 or 2?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597305/multiple-separate-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can put range attribute 
[Range(1, Int32.MaxValue)]

You can put custom range .. For example for range till 29999999 .. You can put 
[Range(1, 29999999)]..
This will satisfy your requirement that number only start with 1 and 2 ..